# NHibernate and Log4Net in Framework 4.0

Tags: nhibernate, .net-4.0, log4net

In our current project we are using NHibernate and so we are using Log4Net as well. When compiling against the 4.0 framework I get warnings about Log4Net.
When checking the Log4Net site I see that activity has been low for quite a while and the buzz on the web is that the project is abandoned.
I also see that there is a move to decouple NHibernate from Log4Net.
Can somebody give me a status update over logging in NHibernate?
Will Log4Net be ported to 4.0? If NHibernate leaves Log4Net, what are the new log candidates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nhibernate 3 uses an internal logger implementation which defaults for log4net (if present) or nologging. There is already an implementation for Common.Logging, an abstraction for loggers which supports several popular logger frameworks. See:

http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/using-nlog-via-common-logging-with-nhibernate.aspx